# href="tel:" and Toll free numbers (0800) variable device behaviour

Tags: android, html, ios, skype

I have a UK client with a toll-free and standard phone number.
On their website there are two clickable `<a href="tel:"/>` links respectively:

```
    <a href="tel:0800000000">0800 000 000</a>
    <a href="tel:+441462000000">+44 1462 000000</a>
```

On clicking the toll-free number different devices handle this in different ways.  My client has an Apple phone which strips the leading 0 and adds +44 (the UK code) which means dialing the number fails. The same happens with Skype.
On my android device, the number is dialed as clicked.

Is there any way to account for this device-specific behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with [WTAI URI](https://www.w3.org/wiki/UriSchemes/wtai)?:

```
<a href="wtai://wp/mc;0800000000">Call 0800-000-000</a>
```

I hope that this work for you!

Keep rocking!